# web browsers constantly crash in 16.04

Tags: nvidia, firefox, crash

Most recently the default web browser (Firefox) crashes. --safe-mode does not help. Removed, etc. reinstalled, still crashes. Installed chrome - crashes. Completely reinstalled (reformat, etc) 16.04.2 Feb 2017 CD - still crashes. On a side note, even though I checked update while install box after first boot there were 11 updates. Firefox still crashes after 11 updates on a virgin install. This is an older i386 machine with Nvidia graphics card. Everythinhg else works fine. Obviously, I write this on a different machine, 64bit laptop, 16.04.

Comment: how did u install the browsers? have u run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: No. I did a virgin installation (reformat, etc) and started wen browser from menu. It crashed. Then I did "Software" from menu, it reported 11 updates. Everything completed, "Your computer is up to date" or something like that. Tried web browser again and it crashed.

Comment: is there a way to check your log? or what crash error do u have? before the browser crashes, do u have any warning.  You can add your computer details. Hardware specs.

Comment: No warning, as soon as I open firefox or chrome it crashes. I suspect my machine is too old, especially the nvidia graphics card.

Comment: whats your machine's specs?

Comment: AMD Athlon XP 2200+, 1023M  DDR_SDRAM, nVidia nForce chipset, nVidia GeForce2 MX 64MB card. I think I found the answer - Firefox, and many other browsers now require SSE2 instructions and my CPU does not have it, so it crashes. If this is the case I suggest Ubuntu software center to warn users before updating.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: @RolandXor - no, thanks for your followup. In the meantime I deleted the 16.04 installation from that old machine. I only have a highly customized Fedora Core-3 installation there that I use as a sandbox, play with linux, C, etc. My working machine is an HP15 laptop with Xubuntu 18.04 and am quite happy with it. This question should be considered answered with my comment about the SSE2 instruction.